# How can I make a div follow my mouse inside of a circle?

Tags: javascript, css

What would be the best approach to have this face always point towards my mouse?  The tricky part for me has been having it skew and scale as if it's rotating around a sphere. (I turned it into a CSS animation to show what I would like it to do)

Thank you so much for your help, and I hope that you have a great day!

```js
const head = document.querySelector('.head');
const face = document.querySelector('.face');

addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  // face follows cursor
  // rotates and scales accordingly
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0) translateY(0px) rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 45deg) scale(1);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(150px) translateY(0px) rotate3d(0, 10, 0, 45deg) scale(0.9);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(0px) translateY(-150px) rotate3d(10, 0, 0, 45deg) scale(0.9);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-100px) translateY(100px) rotate3d(10, 10, 0, 45deg) scale(0.9);
  }
}

.head {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, yellow, #c47400);
  box-shadow: inset -5px -5px 20px yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.head::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 75px;
  top: 75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.35;
  filter: blur(45px)
}

.eye {
  width: 65px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #8a6b0c;
}

.mouth {
  width: 175px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #8a6b0c;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.face {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: move 4s ease infinite;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="head">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="face">
        <div class="eye"></div>
        <div class="eye"></div>
        <div class="mouth"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [First hit on "face follow cursor"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/design-smiley-face-eyes-that-follow-mouse-cursor-using-css-and-js/)

Comment: I think I understand that you want it to look like the whole head, a sphere, turning to face the cursor, but I don’t understand the comment in your code which mentions scaling. When would the head change size?

Comment: @AHaworth I must have forgotten to explain that.  Right now I have a a face div that is moving "around" the head div.  I'm wanting to simulate the look and feel of rotating a sphere, so has the face gets further from the center to the edge, it scales from 1 - 0.9 to make it look like it's farther away.  Similarly to how as the face moves towards the edge of the head, it skews in that direction.  Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the mouse moving in just one plane (the viewport) so the head would always be turned to the left (or the right if it say sat in the middle of the viewport). What would make it say look straight ahead? Or is there some assumption about the mouse being somehow also in 3d space?